# A different interface for the Sql Server Reporting Service?

Tags: sql-server-2005, activex, ssrs

I have a SQL Server 2005 SQL Reporting Services implementation.  It seems that the only way to actually access the reports is for the users to use Internet Explorer.  The web page uses an ActiveX control to do its printing (and probably other functions as well).

Does SSRS have a different way to access its functionality via the web browser?  Like maybe Java or HTML based?  If so, how do I actually turn it on?

The reason I am asking is because the security is being tightened and ActiveX controls will be banished, thus the users won't be able to print.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you've discussed the impact of the "no activex" policy with whoever is proposing it?  You can set the "ie internet zones" appropriately to only allow SSRS ActiveX to be used for certain trusted sites (like internal sites).

A workaround would be to use SSRS schedules to create offline copies of the reports to a file share.  You'd only get "canned" reports, no user parameters or interactive reporting. (Data driven reporting?)

Businesses get a lot of functionality from SSRS and it's effectively free - after you've already paid (a lot of money) for SQL.  You may need to discuss this in more detail with the policy proposer and make them aware of the issue.  You are wasting a lot of money, and it will cost you a lot of time and money to find a replacement.

Unless you want to re-write all you reports again in plain HTML?

Comment: I did, but I am too far down the totem pole.  I'd really like for my users to be able to use Chrome or Firefox.  A lot of the users complain about having to use IE for just this one app.  Thus I am looking for an alternative way to view reports.